# Como criar um seletor para escolher entre Camera, Galeria e Fotos no Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Fala Devs! já dei uma pesquisa, mas não consegui encontrar algo que fosse me ajudar, enfim... Gostaria de criar um menu semelhante a esse da imagem a baixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consigo pegar câmera e galeria normalmente, porém uma função separada da outra! Gostaria que ao apertar para selecionar a foto ficasse com essa barra de seleção para o usuário escolher de onde ele quer fazer o upload da imagem.

```
  public void abrirCamera(){
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
    }

    public void abrirGaleria(){
        intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecione uma imagem"), 2);
    }
```

Comment: Talvez ajude-o: https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet

Comment: Não é bem o que eu preciso, mas pode me ajudar! Obrigado.

Comment: Queria saber porque o cara deu DownLike na pergunta e não disse nada sobre o erro. Falta de respeito com os iniciantes!

Comment: é uma das coisas que mais acontece no site. Infelizmente.

Comment: Sempre acontece isso mesmo, Marcos

Comment: Eu estava tentando implementar isso no meu app e acabei sofrendo bastante. Mas caso alguém se depare com o mesmo ponto, eu achei o material original da primeira resposta útil que vi aqui! Abaixo segue o link com todo o material do cara :D https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/android-capture-image-camera-gallery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opa, tudo bem!?

Segue um código que faz exatamente o que está precisando. Quando clicar no botao chame o método abaixo.

```
public Intent getPickImageChooserIntent()
{
    // Determine Uri of camera image to save.
    Uri outputFileUri = getCaptureImageOutputUri();

    List<Intent> allIntents = new ArrayList<>();
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

    // collect all camera intents
    Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
        if (outputFileUri != null)
        {
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        }
        allIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // collect all gallery intents
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    List<ResolveInfo> listGallery = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(galleryIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listGallery)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(galleryIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
        allIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // the main intent is the last in the list (fucking android) so pickup the useless one
    Intent mainIntent = allIntents.get(allIntents.size() - 1);
    for (Intent intent : allIntents)
    {
        if (intent.getComponent().getClassName().equals("com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity"))
        {
            mainIntent = intent;
            break;
        }
    }
    allIntents.remove(mainIntent);

    // Create a chooser from the main intent
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(mainIntent, "Foto do perfil");

    // Add all other intents
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, allIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[allIntents.size()]));

    return chooserIntent;
}
```

O restante vc irá trabalhar `onActivityResult`, que presumo já está ok.

Abraços!

Comment: Ajudou bastante! Obrigado. Eu também consegui fazer utilizando a biblioteca Cropper. Caso alguém tenha dúvidas sobre esse mesmo assunto.

Comment: Cara a parte de remover imagem tá aí? Tô tendo uma pouco de dor de cabeça para add essa parte de remover a imagem!

Comment: E como eu lanço o startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, TIRAR_FOTO_INTENT_CODE); ou o da galeria para diferenciar? no onActivityResult?